# The ChangeParameters is to use the parameter type of the wrapped function Inner, and then change and provide type to parameters of function Wrapper

Tags: javascript, typescript

**Playground Link:** [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=2&ssc=182&pln=2&pc=3#code/PQKhAICh3AVALApuALgTwA7IMLwIYB2A5ogAp4BOeAtoiohQM7hED2eANuAJbMqvgAro2Qok4DJRp0GqTMlYAzVOIDuVDFgAm4RYIIBjFN1YFwASQIEGAGnCEdYxGYP5iyBxIqsAbty2i8LxyWKgCThJStPRM4EoqyJIGANZ4JLr6RiZmAOoaWBQAdNAZhsamPFYMAIwAFHgAXOAEgtQARrbgbU0t7QwAlE2MKBTcxCV6ZdmV1hQATLWFS5REjD2tHRQA2gC6g+DDo+Mwk1kV6niaDAA8sOCIAB70BFrMi0uSVNRrzRsMu-1wABeAB8BxGYyIINqigITVggKatXehU+NB+uEIJHIXxkTGuOOkMUYtxBdl6mzsh0hIMBoPBRyI-RKOSQZmEiBKBlMw3AFwwllm1WBfPyDFqYyFgK5PJQosugoYcxF-IKEqq82lMHMfMIctg8kYBlGGDlGG81FNKmCY0UrAo1Dw5QIJX5ioo1SRjQZkLs3R9xDpYOpx3lAo1cyRS0KKx+IaIAOBwYh4xKCGQdo4HFYqkhPGY1DQPEtHEQtAIKCd2TsOuc3P0MUQjngFEQiW8bVL32KMGqhXArKLsAAyiw6OAAKIUbwUAD84C2AAluER4F4TKN0DsSjAJw8DIhGIxuD5kMM8ClwAFTWvuZbKHn0FhmAByTHuQnRBgkz94kmwMlfj6CgqRTKEX3sF5wBfVs8C0UwOCLQg0F2F8exgcAAEFwFbXk0S-ChwGoYQ5Q6OJlEIexpzwIsn0QdC5n7QdmlYOVCwORBuSg1QaPI4sMC7ZxK2dP1BDlCJhkQDBmEoBRUjQWcSgAZn7HUDEohCkNcbhEFPa01h3cBkW9ClOn9UyQPAAx1mAoMAyZJMjPqCgiAAfQABiGMC7BWVzPXsnyXNcyN7Ls+NmRgdMujoGIcMPQQODlXg7BtM1WCPbhO0QRSMKcky-ks8yCrsaygM2MKwLs4yvMZP0at9Kz6sDRzwsgEBgEgSA6PAABxOgADFuCYFACXuJ5nFeSCUJ2MEgXAUgxueSatltWR+rsaNVsIgAlHZwHnfrwB6XSGAAbi6+RwGHIJFBGhbHiWmSCGm2b5sWibmBWghFDWjali28Bdv2hdoyB47Twoc7uvfEgDSwAk7FgWA7GwACRXu8aXmYJHgdRo75qhy7MKuF5Roej6pt2OwJ1erZo1IamdkJ0IYcQAAZbhqG4egtF-YkycxybkKpuBkfAVHEferHKb2uaRcG4aRT6lAFeGAkQVegBvEpPLgc7eyaVmOa5nm+e-a5ru4W71cRsWJawkmtFuFG3Fh+RrlVlBbZRgCNfOgBfLZSC2Cy9vJ6XrAh4H3Px6omYulnXcQABVAgOE57mmzN-EMcemXvfFtG5tzin1R+wjzH6XZgdqWtBexu551R6umnMRMmlIc7IGAYBwE9uB5ATnAk+zn8paF56RaRn3XuVz31fH5hI4YEom6T1P05NrOoj-BHRZnkpDaT43M95nf+YZ-fC5BLvuvoYY4cQYU5fy4C6oCxqulYVhS0Ibc78PCgR+yo5oWV2J1U4zpUCANOHUV+lIug2QQaVCygJtYwFbCgQQFAzAAAMAAkms8D+3AAAanAIQtoJDyGEIMP7XBkB-YQMyFA++KBTgLGjCsJB-w9jgHQXFLBODwAEKIS5ehjDOp33YSA8WI9z7m1HtcOi8Q2GwMAhZUCjIQSdUgJA6YPEKBXAoP1fQtxF5GWjPhH4YC+H0njNCWE8I0ElB7n3cwAANAAshOPuvAKD6kuouHMYQryIE4Hybma4xBOnuNOe0OVBHYLMCiWMR8sRkAUTnLJ-4NHFXsrSRyAiMF0GSSIwhsZ6H63AP7AOQ9UAoGfnIjJSi2GP2qOSfJDjwBuP7qYswAB5AA0j03uId8maK-j-cJBBZZgi2PGLRDU2jf1-rM+pKAUCyNZq0wBwDOlvwKaM45fT9DgGGcc2xLUwLgK4ryQxxj+mwBgfoJpDyCj9NqGozI1RAS9KGryfp5yRluOqmVMyPDLIoIKhVRkVVnJuV1osqibl-LIt8iFcK1y4VQDuXKd5DAnkvIILIglJj9BfOJQYOYfze6nMGSC3uyIuEuRsQVRM9jKqOWZcsFyTUEx2OTHC6U3de7Dk4qYHQj96k7JyXMAWedhY7ALvbO44cJ7TRFPLAFco5pzx1erLWOt4TVP8rK3ExJ5WW2tqQQC09C52GJlgUmdsk6Pw9jqlVvsb4lBCiXaWZdZCV2rvOWuFicZN1gC3Cw7cCaMKDuM4CYd67NBOoRecMckT93VUvNNwMQq-PjnolhBjKCPP0PKtVKaUTWMhRyoVNIYRwjgC4mAvTPE+KuhKqCj9wDBNUKEgIETcxiBULEhgM5EmYLKak1l6SPxyoJDk0kByEEOLssUpJwjRGVNwdU2pkiNkoCUiKc1RJvzyrafIDp4LLLdLceKriUrLoXLcYmhBkyVnTL-o5BZ3kP5frWf-S6myAAsp75EWovcovZ8g5irs6Pe3uD7u3PtCP1PA3AuBuKufSZeFBIB4t1EYj5+hnnDEmCeuaZL+kLG+YYX5xzH2SoHqEV9TL6iQvfpM6FtlsWQnhb5JF-7fJopE0FTFXLOVwsI7KYj5aCDkfYfocD1Gy2kZJZSijmQaVMdQ6x5AGGsPHJ5TGOdt762hW5bOog4MBj8cDJ1B99AMBdqfQZ+pw4XPVAVRTJVXrXrB1DhY-D0d8a1H1cNBeObU1R3nAW5k3VXCcWSF5qSTS0sYB81erA8Hb1LOIGCNxypuTTk4igTzLn5X+o1VPO2Ysq2KsnrLBcyq-GKz1QNA1tqjUwF1rAU187sSLutXdO19XHWO2ds09w7rPYBb9r6juFjA0VyrntUNdc84RsLtGtufCO51KS0gFImXZFnZgw-ODCG71gRBFsZLp3vN7TcfGaupXWxGFFQOeARYz0EUYMqEgcpQuKUgEAA)

The type `ChangeParameters` goal is to use the parameter type of the wrapped function `Inner`, and then change and provide this type to the parameters of the package function `Wrapper`.

```
  function inner1(a: number, b: number): string
  function inner2(...args: number[]): string
  function wrapper<T extends (...params: number[]) => string>(fn: T) 
      : ((...params: ChangeParameters<Parameters<T>, number, string>) => string)
```

When we use

```
  const wrapInner1 = wrapper(inner1) 
  const wrapInner2 = wrapper(inner2) 
  I want Typescript prompt this information
  wrapInner1: (a: string, b: string) => string
  wrapInner2: (...args: string[]) => string
```

The following is my implementation, I encountered three problems.

1. Why TS get error?  How to deal with that error? **[High priority]**

> Excessive stack depth comparing types 'ChangeParameters<Parameters, number, string>' and 'readonly any[]'.
> A rest parameter must be of an array type.

2. Why not my second way of implementation, but the steps are okay?
3. I can only achieve this:

```
`((a: number, b: number, c: number) => string) => ((arg_0: string, arg_1: string, arg_2: string) => string)`
```

The better result is, is it possible?

```
`((a: number, b: number, c: number) => string) => ((a: string, b: string, c: string) => string)`
```

```
/** 
  The type ChangeParameters goal is to use the parameter type of the wrapped function Inner, and then provide this type to the parameters of the package function Wrapper.
  function inner1(a: number, b: number): string
  function inner2(...args: number[]): string
  function wrapper<T extends (...params: number[]) => string>(fn: T) : ((...params: ChangeParameters<Parameters<T>, number, string>) => string)
  When use
  const wrapInner1 = wrapper(inner1) 
  const wrapInner2 = wrapper(inner2) 
  I want Typescript prompt this information
  wrapInner1: (a: string, b: string) => string
  wrapInner2: (...args: string[]) => string

  The following is my implementation, I encountered three problems.
  1. Why TS get Error? [High priority]
    Excessive stack depth comparing types 'ChangeParameters<Parameters<T>, number, string>' and 'readonly any[]'.
    A rest parameter must be of an array type.
  2. Why not my second way of implementation, but the steps are okay?
  3. I can only achieve this:
    ((a: number, b: number, c: number) => string) => ((arg_0: string, arg_1: string, arg_2: string) => string)
  The better result is, is it possible?
    ((a: number, b: number, c: number) => string) => ((a: string, b: string, c: string) => string)
*/

type GetFirst<P extends any[]> = P extends [infer F, ...infer R] ? F : never;
type Shift<P extends any[]> = P extends [infer F, ...infer R] ? [...R] : never;
type ChangeType<P, TT, CT> = P extends TT ? CT : P;
type Append<P extends any[], E> = [...P, E];
type ChangeLimitedParameters<P extends any[], TT, CT, T extends any[] = [], First = GetFirst<P>> = {
  0: T;
  1: ChangeLimitedParameters<Shift<P>, TT, CT, Append<T, ChangeType<First, TT, CT>>>;
}[P[number] extends never ? 0 : 1];
type ChangeUnlimitedParameters<P extends any[], TT, CT> = P extends (infer I)[] ? (I extends TT ? CT[] : I[]) : P;

// First Type
type ChangeParameters<P extends any[], TT, CT> = GetFirst<P> extends never
  ? ChangeUnlimitedParameters<P, TT, CT>
  : ChangeLimitedParameters<P, TT, CT>;

type testType1 = [a: number, b: string, c: boolean]
type testType2 = number[]

function testfunc1(a: number, b: number, c: number) {
  return `${a} + ${b} + ${c}`
}

function testfunc2(...arg: number[]) {
  return `${arg}`
}

type ttf2 = ChangeParameters<Parameters<typeof testfunc1>, number, string>


function warpperFun<T extends (...params: number[]) => string>(fn: T) {
  // FIXME Fisrt Type How to deal with that error?
  return (...args: ChangeParameters<Parameters<T>, number, string>) => {
    return `${args}`;
  };
}
type tt1 = ChangeParameters<testType1, number, string> // First Fun OK // [number, number, boolean] => [string, string, boolean]
type tt2 = ChangeParameters<testType2, number, string> // // First Fun OK // number[] => string[]
const warpperFunTestfun1 = warpperFun(testfunc1) // First Fun OK // ((a: number, b: number, c: number) => string) => ((arg_0: string, arg_1: string, arg_2: string) => string) 
const warpperFunTestfun2 = warpperFun(testfunc2) // First Fun OK // ((...args: number[]) => string) => ((...arg: string[]) => string)) 

// Second Type
type ChangeParameters2<P extends any[], TT, CT, T extends any[] = [], First = GetFirst<P>> = {
  0: T;
  1: ChangeParameters2<Shift<P>, TT, CT, Append<T, ChangeType<First, TT, CT>>>;
  2: P extends (infer I)[] ? (I extends TT ? CT[] : I[]) : P;
}[P[number] extends never ? 0 : (First extends never ? 2: 1)];

function warpperFun2<T extends (...params: number[]) => string>(fn: T) {
  // FIXME Second Type How to deal with that error?
  return (...args: ChangeParameters2<Parameters<T>, number, string>) => {
    return `${args}`;
  };
}

type tt3 = ChangeParameters2<testType1, number, string> // Second Type OK // [number, number, boolean] => [string, string, boolean]
type tt4 = ChangeParameters2<testType2, number, string> // // Second Type Fail // number[] => never
const warpperFunTestfun3 = warpperFun2(testfunc1) // Second Type OK // ((a: number, b: number, c: number) => string) => ((arg_0: string, arg_1: string, arg_2: string) => string)
const warpperFunTestfun4 = warpperFun2(testfunc2) // Second Type Fail // ((...args: number[]) => string) => ((...arg: never) => string)

// Step Second Type
type Step1<P extends any[], TT, CT> = P[number] extends never ? 0 : (GetFirst<P> extends never ? 2: 1)
type checkStep1 = Step1<testType2, number, string> // 2 correct
type Step2<P extends any[], TT, CT, T extends any[] = [], First = GetFirst<P>> = {
  0: T;
  1: ChangeParameters2<Shift<P>, TT, CT, Append<T, ChangeType<First, TT, CT>>>;
  2: P extends (infer I)[] ? (I extends TT ? CT[] : I[]) : P;
}
type checkStep2 = Step2<testType2, number, string>[checkStep1] // string[] correct
// Why ChangeParameters2 get never ?
```

**Output**

```
"use strict";
/**
  The type ChangeParameters goal is to use the parameter type of the wrapped function Inner, and then provide this type to the parameters of the package function Wrapper.
  function inner1(a: number, b: number): string
  function inner2(...args: number[]): string
  function wrapper<T extends (...params: number[]) => string>(fn: T) : ((...params: ChangeParameters<Parameters<T>, number, string>) => string)
  When use
  const wrapInner1 = wrapper(inner1)
  const wrapInner2 = wrapper(inner2)
  I want Typescript prompt this information
  wrapInner1: (a: string, b: string) => string
  wrapInner2: (...args: string[]) => string

  The following is my implementation, I encountered three problems.
  1. Why TS get Error? [High priority]
    Excessive stack depth comparing types 'ChangeParameters<Parameters<T>, number, string>' and 'readonly any[]'.
    A rest parameter must be of an array type.
  2. Why not my second way of implementation, but the steps are okay?
  3. I can only achieve this:
    ((a: number, b: number, c: number) => string) => ((arg_0: string, arg_1: string, arg_2: string) => string)
  The better result is, is it possible?
    ((a: number, b: number, c: number) => string) => ((a: string, b: string, c: string) => string)
*/
function testfunc1(a, b, c) {
    return `${a} + ${b} + ${c}`;
}
function testfunc2(...arg) {
    return `${arg}`;
}
function warpperFun(fn) {
    // FIXME Fisrt Type How to deal with that error?
    return (...args) => {
        return `${args}`;
    };
}
const warpperFunTestfun1 = warpperFun(testfunc1); // First Fun OK // ((a: number, b: number, c: number) => string) => ((arg_0: string, arg_1: string, arg_2: string) => string) 
const warpperFunTestfun2 = warpperFun(testfunc2); // First Fun OK // ((...args: number[]) => string) => ((...arg: string[]) => string)) 
function warpperFun2(fn) {
    // FIXME Second Type How to deal with that error?
    return (...args) => {
        return `${args}`;
    };
}
const warpperFunTestfun3 = warpperFun2(testfunc1); // Second Type OK // ((a: number, b: number, c: number) => string) => ((arg_0: string, arg_1: string, arg_2: string) => string)
const warpperFunTestfun4 = warpperFun2(testfunc2); // Second Type Fail // ((...args: number[]) => string) => ((...arg: never) => string)
// Why ChangeParameters2 get never ?
```

**Compiler Options**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "target": "ES2017",
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to coerce types out of the tuple via conditional inferencing (ie Shift, etc). I would just recommend using a mapped tuple type:

```js
type ChangeLimitedParamters<P extends any[], TT, CT> = {
  [K in keyof P]: P[K] extends TT ? CT : P[K]
} & {length: P['length']}
// This also explains why you get arg_0, arg_1,... with your method
// Tuples have key names, and doing it this way we keep the names
```

And if you rewrite your generic in a more friendlier way, you won't receive an error. My best guess is the inferencing engine struggles more if you try to use `Parameters<T>`, instead since we only need the Parameters, why not make that the generic type.

```js
function wrapperFun<T extends number[]>(fn: (..._: T) => string) {
  return (...args: ChangeParameters<T, number, string>) => {
    return `${args}`;
  };
}
```

Then it will work properly without error:

```js
wrapperFunTestfun1('', '', '') // correct
wrapperFunTestfun1(0, 1) //Type '[0, 1]' is not assignable to type '[a: string, b: string, c: string]'
```

[View this on TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w2PpVm)

EDIT:
As for your questions specifically

1. Most likely relates to how you iterate through the tuple, it creates many scopes, and probably is exceeded in the internal engine somewhere. Don't know much more than that.
2. I don't think it recognizes the way you handle the ChangeLimitedParamters<...> as a tuple, since it is so excessively deep/stacked (ie. relates to the first problem).
3. This is because tuple values are key/value pairs on functions (that's how we get named arguments). We keep this by using the mapped tuple type method.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. This answer allows me to add relevant knowledge and solve my question.
There is a problem that there is a problem that it will be `const wrapperFunTestfun1: (...args: ChangeLimitedParamtersNew<[a: number, b: number, c: number], number, string>) => string`, a little bit puzzling. Thanks

Comment: I found a solution:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html
Just need to change it:  `type ChangeLimitedParamtersNew<P extends any[], TT, CT> = {
  [K in keyof P]: P[K] extends TT ? CT : P[K]
} & {length: P['length']}` =>
`type ChangeLimitedParamtersNew<P extends any[], TT, CT> = {
  [K in keyof P]: P[K] extends TT ? CT : P[K]
}`
Thanks